# How to mark element containing class before another class without Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: css

I have list of elements:

```
<ul>
 <li class="one">some text</li>
 <li class="one">some text whit red background</li>
 <li class="two">some text</li>
 <li class="one">some text</li>
 <li class="one">some text</li>
 <li class="one">some text whit red background</li>
 <li class="two">some text</li>
 <li class="one">some text</li>
</ul>
```

I need mark elements with class 'one' only before class 'two'.
This is possible with a clean css?

I tried nth-child and some, but unsuccessfully.

UPDATE.

[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwwSA.jpg)

Comment: The only way that would currently be possible, is if you reversed the order of the elements in the DOM to begin with, and then used flexbox to get them _displayed_ in the reverse order again.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you would like to target all li with a class of "one" that are followed by an li with a class of "two".

If the question was to target li with a class of "one" that follow an li with a class of "two" then the answer would be the adjacent sibling combinator:

```
.two + .one {...}
```

But it seems you need the opposite: a previous sibling combinator. [Here is the question asked on a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector). Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this (in CSS).

Otherwise you can do it with JavaScript.

Comment: yes, correct. I update question.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, none of the methods are suitable.